# Window key commands stopped working on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, aero-snap

I have 2 monitors, and use the Windows snap feature frequently.  In order to use the snap feature to position 4 Windows equally through out 2 different monitors you need to use the Windows key and the arrow keys. I have been doing this for the last few weeks, but now all of a sudden the commands no longer work. Has anyone experienced this? What is the solution?

Answer (score 8):

If this is all Windows key commands, check your keyboard. Some keyboards like Logitech's gaming series have a switch/button for a gaming mode that disables the Windows key. Look for the joystick switch.

Comment: On my Corsair keyboard, the button has a lock with a windows logo on it.

Answer (score 2):

Is it all Win-key hotkeys (eg Win+R for the Run dialog) or just the window-movement keys?

If it is only the window movement keys, then open the *Control Panel*, then *Ease of Access Center*, then *Make the keyboard easier to use*. Now make sure that the *Prevent windows from being automatically arranged…* checkbox under *Make it easier to manage windows* is **not** checked. There is a similar checkbox in *Make the mouse easier to use* to allow/prevent dragging windows to/from the window edges.

If *no* Win-key combinations work, then open the *Group Policy Editor* (`gpedit.msc`) and navigate to `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Explorer` and make sure that *Turn off Windows+X hotkeys* is either **disabled** or **not configured**. (You’ll need to log out and back in or reboot for it to take effect.)

Comment: I tried the ease of access route, and the box you are referring to isn't checked.  how do i get the group policy editor?

Comment: **Run** the command `gpedit.msc`.